# Cluster analysis in R with dummy coded variables

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to run a cluster analysis on a set of data, but unable to find proper insight. Example: I have a set of 50 variables(rows) among 100 resources(columns). Each resource has some variable as strength and other as weakness. I have labelled strength as 1 and weakness as 2. Since, each resource might have only 10 variable as strength and 5 variable as weakness so the other left out variables are marked as zeroes. Now, I want to find the cluster of resources sharing common strengths and weaknesses.

I have used hierarchical clustering and k-means by transposing the dataset so that Resources are in rows. The k-means plot showed too much of overlap among different clusters, hence using hierarchical clustering only. I have replaced 1 (strength) with +10 and 2(weakness) with -10, to see if the cluster algorithm responds differently, but still it is not much of a help.

Any inputs to improve this methodology and alternative ways of handling this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with clustering binary data (and low cardinality, and categorical dummy encoded data) is that it's binary information.

Methods such as k-means are designed for *continuous* variables, where the mean is meaningful, and almost every distance is unique.

With binary data, everything tends to change at the same time. You have many duplicate records. You have records that differ in 1 position, in 2 positions etc. - in your case, they can differ in at most 30 positions, so you have 31 levels of similarity.

The solution often is to move from a clustering to a itemset mining view. This is not fundamentally different to clustering, but it begins with a binary assumption: either an item is present in a transaction, or it is not. The resulting itemsets then correspond to frequent combinations, e.g. rows that have A and B tend to have C.

Try that, frequent itemsets and assoication rules.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have not tried association rules. Can you please provide me with a dummy code/flowchart/link to examples? I would essentially cluster the resources, so have to transpose the data frame so that resources are in rows and variables are in columns.

Comment: Grab your favorite data mining book, read the chapter on association rules.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help you make dummy/ binary variables.

```
settingStrength <- as.numeric(setting.g == "Strength")
settingWeakness   <- as.numeric(setting.g == "Weakness")
```

I called the hierarchial cluster focussing on the columns 3 and 4 of your dataset. You cannot cluster 100 dimensions and plot them in a two-dimensional plot. You have to reduce dimensionality first. You are right be choosing hierarchical clustering, because k-means requires that you know the number of clusters and you do not know them

```
CLUSTER <- hclust(dist(YOURDATA[, 3:4]))
plot(CLUSTER)
```

However if you use k-means you should not have only a look at the plot. In the following I have chosen three groups of clustering.

```
KMEANSCLUSTER <- kmeans(YOURDATASET[,3:4],3)
KMEANSCLUSTER[1]
```

Now you should see a vector of with the length of 15 (the length of your data) and values 1,2 & 3. The value to whether the variable belongs to cluster "1", cluster "2" or cluster "3".

Comment: thanks. I have to identify and dummy code it myself as 1-Strength, 2-Weakness, 0-No identification. Will replacing 1 with +10 and 2 with -10, make any different sense for the hierarchical clustering algorithm? Also, how can i reduce dimensionality (100 resources) and then do clustering, as I want to view which resource are in which cluster? And to find the loadings of the strengths and weakness across the cluster i have used the mean of frequency of the variable in that cluster. Example for cluster 1 comprising of 10 resource, if X strength is noticed in 5 resource, the loading is 0.5,correct?

Comment: Have you thought about including 2 binary variables? First variable: 1-Strength 0- else; Second variable 1- Weakness 0- else. No identification will give you 0 for both binary variables.

Comment: You can reduce dimensionalty with PCA and plotting clusters of the reduced dataset. You just have to interpret the variables. And assigning the value +10 and -10 will not give you any better results. It just makes the interpretation more difficult.

Comment: Thanks. So, it means I have to create 3 extra columns in the spreadsheet for each resource. 100*3=300 columns? If that is the case then 2 extra columns would do i think. Resource A strength column (1-strength,0), Resource A weakness column (1-Weakness,0). Sorry if you meant something different?

Comment: Great. This is what I meant. If you want to include "n" categories as binary variables in a dataset you need to include "n-1" binary variables. One for each category except of the reference category. In you case "n" = 3 and "n-1" = 2

Comment: Thanks. Which means, assuming no PCA done at this stage- I will end up with a cluster where Cluster 1 will have " Ankur Strength, John Weakness, Sam Strength" and Cluster 2 will have "Ankur Weakness, John Strength, Peter Weakness,Sam Weakness"?

Comment: Avoiding PCA It is possible to cluster two vector (=two rows in a matrix) and visualise them in a two-dimensional plot.

Comment: So, I have created two columns per resource (Strength and Weakness column), a total of 200 columns. Rows will have the variables. Now, for clustering of these resources (by transposing the dataset), using hierarchical clustering i will have a cluster column number corresponding to each resource (strength and weakness). How can I find the loadings of the variables in this case, earlier I have used the mean of frequency of the variable in that cluster?

Comment: Also, with this new data set of 200 columns, you suggested to run a PCA and do a clustering of those 200 resources(Resource Strength and Resource Weakness). Can you please provide me a flow chart on how to go about this? A sample code would be very helpful. Thanks you so much for your valuable time and suggestions

Comment: http://planspace.org/2013/02/03/pca-3d-visualization-and-clustering-in-r/ I found an example, that is pretty similar to yours. 1. Create binary variables. 2 Reduce Dimensionality 3. Run a Clustering Algorithm (e.g. hierarchical clustering) 4. Plot the data and the clusters

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering how sensible it would be to do a PCA on binary coded variables